# Cut line on Gallery package in Android

Tags: android, package, gallery

I am new to android I was trying to use Gallery but whenever I declare & import gallery it put a Line on it in the mid. what is the reason of it? 
and how to make it ok? 
[Here is ScreenShoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvpws.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That line means that the Gallery class is deprecated. You could use HorizontalScrollView or ViewPager instead.